# Como posso comparar as chaves de uma hash com uma entrada do usuário?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Arquivo:

```
101;Johnny 'wave-boy' Jones;USA;8.32;Fish;21
102;Juan Martino;Spain;9.01;Gun;36
103;Joseph 'smitty' Smyth;USA;8.85;Cruizer;18
104;Stacey O'Neill;Ireland;8.91;Malibu;22
105;Aideen 'board babe' Wu;Japan;8.65;Fish;24
106;Zack 'bonnie-lad' MacFadden;Scotland;7.82;Thruster;26
107;Aaron Valentino;Italy;8.98;Gun;19
```

Código:

```
arquivo = open("surfing_data.csv")
rexh = {}
for linha in arquivo:
    (ID, nome, pais, média, prancha, idade) = linha.split(";")
    rexh[ID] = nome,pais,média,prancha,idade
escolha = int(input("qual o id do surfista desejado : "))
```

Como posso comparar as chaves da hash 'rexh' com o input do usuário para assim obter o 'id' do surfista certo?

Minha ideia é a de comparar as IDs(os números 101...107) com o input do usuário para assim selecionar e mostrar ao usuário as informações (os valores da hash) para ele do respectivo surfista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apesar de vc já ter uma resposta boa, vale notar que o seu código já funciona e vc *não precisa da biblioteca csv*.

O seu dicionário `rexh` já está sendo criado com os dados dos surfistas. Para acessar um deles, basta usar o ID dado pelo usuário como chave: `rexh[escolha]`. Mas você não deve converter a variável `escolha` para inteiro, já que não faz essa conversão quando adiciona a variável `ID` em `rexh`.

Ou seja, faça assim:

```
arquivo = open("surfing_data.csv")
rexh = {}
for linha in arquivo:
    (ID, nome, pais, média, prancha, idade) = linha.split(";")
    rexh[ID] = nome,pais,média,prancha,idade
escolha = input("qual o id do surfista desejado : ") # <== Sem conversação do ID para inteiro

print(rexh[escolha])
```

Ou assim:

```
arquivo = open("surfing_data.csv")
rexh = {}
for linha in arquivo:
    (ID, nome, pais, média, prancha, idade) = linha.split(";")
    rexh[int(ID)] = nome,pais,média,prancha,idade # <== Com conversão do ID para inteiro aqui
escolha = int(input("qual o id do surfista desejado : ")) # <== E aqui também

print(rexh[escolha])
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) para fazer o [parsing](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) no arquivo CSV e procurar por algum valor de um determinado campo.

No seu caso o valor a ser pesquisado seria o `ID` fornecido pelo usuário, veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
import csv

id = raw_input("Informe o ID: ")
resultado = ""

with open("execsv.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for registro in reader:
        if id == registro[0]:
            resultado = registro

if resultado:
    print (resultado)
else:
    print("Nada encontrado!")
```

Entrada ID

> 107

Saída

> ['107', 'Aaron Valentino', 'Italy', '8.98', 'Gun', '19']

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757743/how-can-i-get-a-specific-field-of-a-csv-file).